# How to convert image url to uri or file and post in react-native?

Tags: react-native

For example, image URL is 'https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg'

I want to this it to upload/post to a server with file format like 'multipart/form-data'.

how should I extract file URI from the URL?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my simple code FormData with react-native to post request with string and image.

I have used react-native-image-picker to capture/select photo [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker)

```
let photo = { uri: source.uri}
let formdata = new FormData();

formdata.append("product[name]", 'test')
formdata.append("product[images_attributes[0][file]]", {uri: photo.uri, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'multipart/form-data'})


fetch('http://192.168.1.101:3000/products',{
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  body: formdata
  }).then(response => {
    console.log("image uploaded")
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })  
});
```

Comment: But it doesn't  seem to work. it converts `{uri: photo.uri, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'multipart/form-data'}` to `[object Object]` string and sends it to server.

Comment: This seems to be leaving out a critical component: where does `source.uri` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Did some quick search, give this solution a try

```
var file;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'your image url', true);
xhr.onload = function(e) {
if (this.status == 200) {
    file = new File([this.response],'fileName');
}
};
xhr.send();
```